# Using pairwise comparision on gls object

Tags: generalized-least-squares, tukey-hsd-test, lsmeans

I have one factor (tree genotype) and I analyse its influence on soil content.  I used gls to aply weights on my data because it's a better fitted model.

Here is an exemple of my data with one variable (potassium) :

```
> dataK <- structure(list(Genotype = c("PB08", "PB08", "PB08", "PB09", "PB09", 
+                                      "PB09", "PB10", "PB10", "PB10", "PB13", "PB13", "PB13", "PB16", 
+                                      "PB16", "PB21", "PB21", "PB21", "PB23", "PB23", "PB23", "PB25", 
+                                      "PB25", "PB25", "PB29", "PB29", "PB29", "PB33", "PB33", "PB33"
+ ), K = c(0.85299241359094, 0.465133054980756, 0.00690267582675159, 
+          1.01673068757058, 1.030275834371, 0.834524714326693, 1.03316209040447, 
+          1.10298412805863, 1.18155841491109, 0.838705999451807, 0.883919392948746, 
+          0.901960535626635, 0.75594651348742, 0.756023068853717, 0.958311561443041, 
+          0.673810456005313, 1.08746537546638, 0.960314352517763, 1.0648664379158, 
+          1.00746055772745, 0.847776805354443, 1.03812953182887, 0.919747454011172, 
+          0.632561226408033, 0.664781889579858, 0.833083943531637, 0.92164628717724, 
+          0.622415179403636, 1.03783101178149)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(1L, 
+                                                                                     2L, 3L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 39L, 40L, 
+                                                                                     46L, 47L, 48L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 83L, 
+                                                                                     84L, 85L))
```

I know there's a significative difference between my groups so I wanted to do a pairwise comparision with `emmeans()` but I get an error when I try to look at the output :

```
> model <- gls(K~Genotype, weights=varIdent(form=~1|Genotype), data=dataK)
> means <- emmeans(model, ~Genotype)
> pairs(means, simple="Genotype")
 contrast    estimate     SE   df t.ratio p.value
 PB08 - PB09  -0.5188 0.2525 2.37 -2.054  0.6378 
 PB08 - PB10  -0.6642 0.2483 2.25 -2.676  0.4608 
 PB08 - PB13  -0.4332 0.2452 2.14 -1.766  0.7402 
 PB08 - PB16  -0.3143 0.2445 2.11 -1.285  0.8970 
 PB08 - PB21  -0.4649 0.2734 2.98 -1.701  0.7626 
 PB08 - PB23  -0.5692 0.2464 2.17 -2.310  0.5631 
 PB08 - PB25  -0.4935 0.2507 2.31 -1.968  0.6683 
 PB08 - PB29  -0.2685 0.2523 2.42 -1.064  0.9545 
 PB08 - PB33  -0.4190 0.2741 3.06 -1.529  0.8276 
 PB09 - PB10  -0.1454 0.0763 3.53 -1.906  0.6793 
 PB09 - PB13   0.0856 0.0659 2.37  1.300  0.8960 
 PB09 - PB16   0.2045 0.0631 2.01  3.241  0.3631 
 PB09 - PB21   0.0540 0.1375 3.33  0.393  1.0000 
 PB09 - PB23  -0.0504 0.0700 2.89 -0.720  0.9954 
 PB09 - PB25   0.0253 0.0840 4.03  0.301  1.0000 
 PB09 - PB29   0.2504 0.0886 3.92  2.826  0.3479 
 PB09 - PB33   0.0999 0.1389 2.99  0.719  0.9956 
 PB10 - PB13   0.2310 0.0468 2.75  4.936  0.1254 
 PB10 - PB16   0.3499 0.0429 2.00  8.164     NaN 
 PB10 - PB21   0.1994 0.1295 2.77  1.540  0.8217 
 PB10 - PB23   0.0950 0.0525 3.60  1.812  0.7179 
 PB10 - PB25   0.1707 0.0701 3.80  2.434  0.4717 
 PB10 - PB29   0.3958 0.0755 3.37  5.241  0.0799 
 PB10 - PB33   0.2453 0.1310 2.43  1.873  0.7002 
 PB13 - PB16   0.1189 0.0188 2.00  6.319  0.1170 
 PB13 - PB21  -0.0317 0.1236 2.33 -0.256  1.0000 
 PB13 - PB23  -0.1360 0.0356 3.35 -3.820  0.1882 
 PB13 - PB25  -0.0604 0.0586 2.50 -1.030  0.9615 
 PB13 - PB29   0.1647 0.0650 2.28  2.536  0.4949 
 PB13 - PB33   0.0142 0.1252 2.07  0.114  1.0000 
 PB16 - PB21  -0.1505 0.1222 2.23 -1.232  0.9133 
 PB16 - PB23  -0.2549 0.0302 1.99 -8.432     NaN 
 PB16 - PB25  -0.1792 0.0555 2.04 -3.230  0.3624 
 PB16 - PB29   0.0458 0.0622 1.93  0.737     NaN 
 PB16 - PB33  -0.1046 0.1237 1.98 -0.846     NaN 
 PB21 - PB23  -0.1044 0.1259 2.50 -0.829  0.9875 
 PB21 - PB25  -0.0287 0.1342 3.08 -0.214  1.0000 
 PB21 - PB29   0.1964 0.1371 3.29  1.432  0.8634 
 PB21 - PB33   0.0459 0.1739 4.21  0.264  1.0000 
 PB23 - PB25   0.0757 0.0632 3.16  1.197  0.9322 
 PB23 - PB29   0.3007 0.0691 2.78  4.350  0.1651 
 PB23 - PB33   0.1502 0.1274 2.22  1.180  0.9266 
 PB25 - PB29   0.2251 0.0833 3.87  2.701  0.3845 
 PB25 - PB33   0.0746 0.1356 2.78  0.550  0.9992 
 PB29 - PB33  -0.1505 0.1385 2.88 -1.087  0.9542 

P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 10 estimates 
Warning message:
In ptukey(sqrt(2) * abst, fam.size, zapsmall(df), lower.tail = FALSE) :
  production de NaN
```

I tried to do the same without the weights and it worked :

```
> model <- gls(K~Genotype, data=dataK)
> means <- emmeans(model, ~Genotype)
> pairs(means, simple="Genotype")
 contrast    estimate    SE df t.ratio p.value
 PB08 - PB09  -0.5188 0.148 19 -3.505  0.0560 
 PB08 - PB10  -0.6642 0.148 19 -4.488  0.0073 
 PB08 - PB13  -0.4332 0.148 19 -2.927  0.1649 
 PB08 - PB16  -0.3143 0.165 19 -1.899  0.6697 
 PB08 - PB21  -0.4649 0.148 19 -3.141  0.1124 
 PB08 - PB23  -0.5692 0.148 19 -3.846  0.0282 
 PB08 - PB25  -0.4935 0.148 19 -3.334  0.0780 
 PB08 - PB29  -0.2685 0.148 19 -1.814  0.7200 
 PB08 - PB33  -0.4190 0.148 19 -2.830  0.1944 
 PB09 - PB10  -0.1454 0.148 19 -0.982  0.9900 
 PB09 - PB13   0.0856 0.148 19  0.579  0.9998 
 PB09 - PB16   0.2045 0.165 19  1.236  0.9565 
 PB09 - PB21   0.0540 0.148 19  0.365  1.0000 
 PB09 - PB23  -0.0504 0.148 19 -0.340  1.0000 
 PB09 - PB25   0.0253 0.148 19  0.171  1.0000 
 PB09 - PB29   0.2504 0.148 19  1.691  0.7873 
 PB09 - PB33   0.0999 0.148 19  0.675  0.9994 
 PB10 - PB13   0.2310 0.148 19  1.561  0.8506 
 PB10 - PB16   0.3499 0.165 19  2.114  0.5394 
 PB10 - PB21   0.1994 0.148 19  1.347  0.9291 
 PB10 - PB23   0.0950 0.148 19  0.642  0.9996 
 PB10 - PB25   0.1707 0.148 19  1.153  0.9714 
 PB10 - PB29   0.3958 0.148 19  2.674  0.2512 
 PB10 - PB33   0.2453 0.148 19  1.657  0.8050 
 PB13 - PB16   0.1189 0.165 19  0.718  0.9990 
 PB13 - PB21  -0.0317 0.148 19 -0.214  1.0000 
 PB13 - PB23  -0.1360 0.148 19 -0.919  0.9937 
 PB13 - PB25  -0.0604 0.148 19 -0.408  1.0000 
 PB13 - PB29   0.1647 0.148 19  1.113  0.9771 
 PB13 - PB33   0.0142 0.148 19  0.096  1.0000 
 PB16 - PB21  -0.1505 0.165 19 -0.910  0.9941 
 PB16 - PB23  -0.2549 0.165 19 -1.540  0.8596 
 PB16 - PB25  -0.1792 0.165 19 -1.083  0.9807 
 PB16 - PB29   0.0458 0.165 19  0.277  1.0000 
 PB16 - PB33  -0.1046 0.165 19 -0.632  0.9996 
 PB21 - PB23  -0.1044 0.148 19 -0.705  0.9991 
 PB21 - PB25  -0.0287 0.148 19 -0.194  1.0000 
 PB21 - PB29   0.1964 0.148 19  1.327  0.9347 
 PB21 - PB33   0.0459 0.148 19  0.310  1.0000 
 PB23 - PB25   0.0757 0.148 19  0.511  0.9999 
 PB23 - PB29   0.3007 0.148 19  2.032  0.5895 
 PB23 - PB33   0.1502 0.148 19  1.015  0.9874 
 PB25 - PB29   0.2251 0.148 19  1.521  0.8679 
 PB25 - PB33   0.0746 0.148 19  0.504  0.9999 
 PB29 - PB33  -0.1505 0.148 19 -1.017  0.9873 

P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 10 estimates
```

Since I whan to consider the weights, what can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: The problem is that the ptukey() function kind of goes belly-up when the df are too small. You might try using `adjust = “mvt”`.

Comment: Or try `mode = "df.error"` to disable using the Satterthwaite method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than `emmeans` I would recommend that you use the `predictmeans::predictmeans()` function in `R`- It will allow you to do pairwise comparisons, and allow you to correct your family-wise error rate for these additional p-values. I believe it is also fine with weights.

Comment: I verified that if you run `predictmeans(..., adj = "tukey", Df = 1.9)` you get NaNs as well. This is because the R function `ptukey()` does not work for df < 2 (and those are exactly the cases where `emmeans()` produced NaNs. Also, just try `ptukey(1,4,1.9)`; you'll get `NaN` and a warning message. Thus, this answer does not solve the problem in any real sense, though it might hide the issue behind a different d.f. calculation.